# Passing an SDL KeyboardState(Uint8*) to Lua

Tags: c++, sdl, lua, sdl2

I'm working on my first big project and I've decided to integrate Lua with my C++ framework. Everything's worked out so far, but the only way I've managed to pass the `SDL_GetKeyboardState(NULL)` array to Lua is by building a Lua table manually.

```
void passKeyboard(const Uint8* keyboard){
    std::map<std::string,std::string> kmap;
    kmap.clear();
    kmap["UP"]=toString(keyboard[SDL_GetScancodeFromKey(SDLK_UP)]);
    kmap["DOWN"]=toString(keyboard[SDL_GetScancodeFromKey(SDLK_DOWN)]);
    kmap["LEFT"]=toString(keyboard[SDL_GetScancodeFromKey(SDLK_LEFT)]);
    kmap["RIGHT"]=toString(keyboard[SDL_GetScancodeFromKey(SDLK_RIGHT)]);
    ...
    vbind_SetTable("keyboard",kmap);
}
```

Now, the code works and is reasonably fast for my purposes, but it's undeniably ugly. I even feel dirty looking at it. Is there any way I could to this more elegantly?

For reference, `vbind.h`:

```
void vbind_SetTable(const std::string &name,std::map<std::string,std::string> &t){
    lua_newtable(L);
    for(std::map<std::string,std::string>::iterator it=t.begin();it!=t.end();it++){
        lua_pushstring(L,it->first.c_str());
        std::string value=it->second;
        const char* p=value.c_str();
        char* end;
        long t=strtol(value.c_str(),&end,10);
        if(p!=end&&errno!=ERANGE){
            lua_pushnumber(L,t);
        }
        else{
            lua_pushstring(L,value.c_str());
        }
        lua_settable(L,-3);
    }
    lua_setglobal(L,name.c_str());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit hard on the eyes. And... you are doing a LOT of work just to get a keyboard state. Take a look at the LuaSDL implementation.

https://github.com/Tangent128/luasdl2/blob/master/src/keyboard.c#L128

Follow it to KeysIndex at Line 29. You will probably notice that he used the original function, as well as a checkinteger() function from the Lua library, and compares the data to registered Enums. A pretty simple solution from this code.

```
SDL_GetKeyboardState(int *numkeys)
{
    SDL_Keyboard *keyboard = &SDL_keyboard;

    if (numkeys != (int *) 0) {
        *numkeys = SDL_NUM_SCANCODES;
    }
    return keyboard->keystate;
}
```

So instead of using a map, you can actually just write to a pre-existing table.

Answer (score 0):

First - have you considered Sol2 for lua binding (https://github.com/ThePhD/sol2)? It's very easy to use, I love it.

With it, you could register a function to lua which takes a string and returns bool if the key is pressed:

```
// something like this
bool KeyPressed(const std::string &key_name)
{
    auto key = SDL_GetKeyFromName(key_name.c_str());
    if (key == SDLK_UNKNOWN)
        return false;

    auto state = SDL_GetKeyboardState(NULL);
    return state[SDL_GetScancodeFromKey(key)];
}
```

With Sol2, it is super each to register a function to lua (and you can easily integrate it with plain lua API stuff):

```
// sol2
sol::state lua;
// Or use sol::state_view(lua_State *L) with
// an existing lua_State
// i.e. 
//    sol::state_view lua(L);
lua.set_function("keypressed", KeyPressed);
```

Then in your lua code, you can use the KeyPressed function as you would expect:

```
if keypressed("Left") then
    -- do stuff
end
```